# BS4 парсит только одну страницу

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пояснение ниже.Вот код:

```
page = 1
steam_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p'
pattern = '\$(\d+\.\d{2}) USD'
while page < 500:
    r = requests.get(steam_url + str(page))
    print(steam_url + str(page))
    soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
    all = soup.find_all('a', class_='market_listing_row_link')
    page += 1
```

#p в steam_url означает, какая страница будет парситься, этот p я изменяю, url меняется с steam_url1 на steam_url2, но парсится только 1 страница.Объясните пожалуйста, почему.

Comment: Потому что вы каждый раз сохраняйте в переменную all другую страницу. И еще для этого лучше цикл

Comment: Мне приходят одинаковые response,не знаю с чем это связано

Answer (score 0):

Хоть ссылки и меняются, но response приходит одинаковый.Я немного подкоректировал url и все начало работать

---

В конце должна быть строка "_popular_desc" она не появлялась при запросах.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит _"немного подкоректировал url"_? Может ли это быть связано с кэшированием?

Comment: В конце должна быть строка "_popular_desc" она не появлялась при запросах.